# Почему CLR использует com объекты для совместимости управляемого и нативного кода?

Tags: .net, visual-c++, c++-cli

У меня есть C++/cli обвязка, которая использует c++ библиотеку (которая не использует com). Меня удивил тот факт, что если явно пометить все управляемые классы атрибутом ComVisible(false), то я получаю ошибку времени исполнения "query interface was made from non com visible class". Этот интерфейс вообще com'вский. Не понимаю, как такая ситуация вообще возможна. Я предполагал, что clr использует pinvoke вызовы для таких целей.

Иерархия классов следующая:

Отрывок нативного кода (выпадает в process (при вызове функтора))

```
// Native code
class NativeItem
{
public:
     template<class ItemType>
     void process(const std::function<void(ItemType&)>& functor)
     {
        for (auto location = m_components.begin(); location != m_components.end(); ++location)
           functor(**location);
     }
// Some stuff
      std::vector<NativeItem*> m_components;
};
```

Отрывок C++/Cli кода:

```
inline System::IntPtr convert(System::Delegate^ source_delegate)
{
    return    System::Runtime::InteropServices::Marshal::GetFunctionPointerForDelegate(source_delegate);
} 

[System::Runtime::InteropServices::ComVisibleAttribute(false)]
public ref class ManagedItem
{
protected:
     ManagedItem(NativeItem& native_item) : m_native_item(native_item)
     {
     }
private:
     NativeItem& m_native_item;
};

public ref class DerivedManagedItem : ManagedItem
{
public:
     DerivedManagedItem(NativeItem& native_item) : ManagedItem(native_item)
     {
     }
};

public ref class Manager
{
public:
   typedef void (*create_managed_item_func)(NativeItem& item);

   delegate DerivedManagedItem^ CreateManagedItemDelegate(NativeItem& item);

   DerivedManagedItem^ create_item(NativeItem& item)
   {
       return gcnew DerivedManagedItem(item);
   }

   void process(NativeItem& item)
   {
        CreateManagedItemDelegate^ create_item_delegate = gcnew CreateManagedItemDelegate(this, &Manager::create_item);
        create_managed_item_func function_pointer = static_cast<create_managed_item_func>(convert(create_item_delegate).ToPointer());
        component.process(function_pointer);
        System::GC::KeepAlive(create_item_delegate);
   }
};
```

Comment: с# предполагает по-умолчанию, что классы используемые библиотекой c++ будут com-овские.

Comment: этот момент непонятен, почему crt использует com технологию, я думал она существует только для совместимости старых com- классов

Comment: Несовсем правильно ответил, у c# возможен обмен с native(c++) только классами относящимися к COM, у С# есть процедуры которые "помогают" привести класс к COM-совместимому (построитель того же IDIspatch что б получить доступ к полям класса), при попытке пустить на экспорт(обмен) COM-несовместимый класс вы получаете исключение. Из COM используется достаточно узкий набор интерфейсов, которые обеспечивают видимость класса и управление памятью: IUnknown, IDispatch и несколько других.

Comment: А зачем c# приводить код к com совместимому. C++/Cli как раз используется чтобы не создавать такие классы. C++ / cli может проводить явный/неявный маршаллинг. Откуда вообще необходимость в com технологии

Comment: Приведите всётаки пример который даёт вам ошибку, на примере можно показать. Сама CLR-машина использует COM для старта и распределения памяти. Видимо нужен "базовый" класс от которого можно оттолкнуться, и microsoft похоже выбрали COM.

Comment: @nick_n_a пожалуйста, не сочиняйте. Ни C#, ни C++/cli не требуется com-видимость для работы.

Comment: @AlexAkel приведите полный текст ошибки и трассировку стека!

Comment: да, извините, сейчас приведу полный текст и трассировку

Comment: Проблему уже нашел, оказывается у меня при вызове функции в нативном коде возвращался управляемый объект. Это можно увидеть по сигнатуре CreateManagedItemDelegate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Из комментария пользователя [@AlexAkel](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/217357/alexakel):*

Проблему уже нашел. Оказывается, у меня при вызове функции в нативном коде возвращался управляемый объект. Это можно увидеть по сигнатуре делегата `CreateManagedItemDelegate`.